# Swift Up or Down game

Tags: swift, xcode

I need help with creating an up or down game with cards.
I've been messing around trying a lot of different variables, but I can't make it work. A card is displayed on the screen, and there are two buttons you can press, up or down. If your current card is 10 and the next card is 5, if you press down, you get awarded a point, and vice versa.

But my program messes up and doesn't get the right numbers. Can anyone see the error?

```
var upScore = 0
var downScore = 0
var totalScore = 0
var startingCard: Int = 0
var currentCard: Int = 0
var nextCard: Int = 0

var currentNumber: Int = 0


@IBAction func startTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    startingCard = Int.random(in: 0...12)
    cardImage.image = clubsCards[startingCard]
    currentCard = startingCard + 1

    print("position in deck: " + "\(startingCard)")
    currentNumber = startingCard + 1
    print("current card number: " + "\(currentNumber)")
}





@IBAction func cardUp(_ sender: UIButton) {
    nextCard = Int.random(in: 0...12)

    if nextCard + 1 > currentCard {
        cardImage.image = clubsCards[nextCard]

        upScore += 1
        totalScore = upScore + downScore
        upOrDownScore.text = "\(totalScore)"

        currentCard = nextCard + 1

    } else {
        let lossUpAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Feil", message: "Du tapte! Drikk " + "\(upScore)" + " slurk(er)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        lossUpAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(lossUpAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)



        totalScore = 0
        upOrDownScore.text = "\(totalScore)"
        cardImage.image = nil
    }
}


@IBAction func cardDown(_ sender: UIButton) {
    nextCard = Int.random(in: 0...12)

    if nextCard + 1 < currentCard {
        cardImage.image = clubsCards[nextCard]

        downScore += 1
        totalScore = upScore + downScore
        upOrDownScore.text = "\(totalScore)"

        currentCard = nextCard + 1

    } else {
        let lossDownAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Feil", message: "Du tapte! Drikk " + "\(totalScore)" + " slurk(er)", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        lossDownAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(lossDownAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)


        totalScore = 0
        upOrDownScore.text = "\(totalScore)"
        cardImage.image = nil
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what do you mean by messes up? what does it mean to not get the right numbers?

Comment: “messes up and doesn't get the right numbers” Is too vague. Give actual input, actual actions, actual output, and expected output.

Comment: My bad. When I press the up button and get it correct, it displays the current score and gives me a new picture. But when I press the down button and get it right, it adds 2 points to the score. And when I don't get it correct, it just displays "0" on the alert, instead of the current score. Also sometimes when I press down, the game just continiues even if the next card was higher.

Comment: You have a wonderful debugger. Debug! You can follow along in your code line by line, see where it goes, watch as the variables change. Figure out what’s happening.

Comment: in cardDown, isn't `currentCard` supposed to be `currentCard = nextCard - 1`? instead of `+ 1`?

Comment: yes thank you. but i still can't manage to get it right when pressing the down button,even if the next card is higher, and i press lower, it accepts it, and then after a few more clicks it crashes

Comment: i added some prints to the code to see in the console, and it seems that when I get a card number, and press down, it just locks on to that number and doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using upscore and downscore, why not just have a totalscore? This score can increment by one each time the person gets a correct answer and decrement by one each time they get it wrong.

Comment: I understand. My main problem is making the cards renew for every time I click up or down. It works when pressing the up button, but not the down button. It just stays on the same card every time